# FFTW 3.3.3 basic usage with real datas

Tags: c++, fftw

I'm a newbie in FFT and I was asked to find a way to analyse/process a particular set of data collected by oil drilling rigs.
There is a lot of noise in the collected data due to rig movements (up & down with tides and waves for example).
I was asked to clean the collected data up with FFT=>filtering=>IFFT.

I use C++ and the FFTW 3.3.3 library.

An example is better than anything else so :

I have a DB with, for example, the mudflow (liters per minutes). The mudflow is collected every 5 seconds, there is a timestamp in the DB for every measure (ex. 1387411235).

So my IN_data for my FFT is a couple of timestamp/mudflow (ex. 1387456630/3955.94, 1387456635/3954.92, etc...)

Displaying theses data really looks like a noisy sound signal and relevant events may be masked by the noise.

Using examples found on the Internet I can manage to perform FFT but my lack of knowledge and understanding is a big problem as I've never worked on signal processing and Fourier Transforms.

I don't really know how to proceed to start with this job, which version of FFTW routine to use (c2c, r2c, etc...), if there is any pre-data-processing and/or post-processing to do.
There are a lot of examples and tutorials that I've read on the internet but I'm french (sorry for my mistakes here) and it doesn't always make sense to me especially with OUT_data units, OUT_data type, In and Out data array size, windowing (what is that by the way), to put it in a nutshell I'm lost...

I suppose that my problem would be pretty straightforward for someone used to FFTW but for me it's very complicated right now.

So my questions :

- What FFTW routine to use in both ways (FFT & IFFT) (what kind, type and size, of array for IN_data and OUT_data).
- How to interpret the resulting array (what are the units that FFTW will return).

For now a short sample of what I've done is :

```
fftw_plan p;
p  = (fftw_plan)fftw_plan_dft_1d(size,in,out,FFTW_FORWARD,FFTW_ESTIMATE);
fftw_execute(p);
fftw_destroy_plan(p);
```

with "in" and "out" as fftw_complex (the complex element of my In_data array is set to 1 for every data, don't really know why but the tutorial said to do that).

This code is based on an example found on the Internet but my lack of knowledge/understanding is a big drag and I was wondering if there was someone here who could give me explanations/workflow/insights/links on how to pull this out.

I'm in a trial period for my new job and I really want to implement this feature for my boss even if it means asking around for help, I've seen a lot of FFTW skilled posts here...

Comment: Don't apologize for being french ;)

Comment: I apologize more on my lack of skills/knowledge my friend... but thank's anyway...

Comment: FFTW is a rather complex package for a complete DSP noob - I suggest starting with something much simpler, e.g. [KissFFT](http://sourceforge.net/projects/kissfft/). Also you need to be certain that your data is uniformly sampled, otherwise an FFT-based approach is not going to work.

Comment: Thank's Paul for your answer, the measure is done every 5 seconds so I guess that the sampling is uniform (on rare cases the data is not collected but there is always the corresponding timestamp in the DB).

Comment: OK - my point was that for uniformly sampled data it needs to be exactly 5 seconds between samples, with no missing data points, otherwise you will need a more complex method than FFT.

Comment: I can always duplicate data from previous entry in the input array if I find missing data points to "uniformize" my set of data. We are not sending human beings in space here, I have a little error margin I guess...

Answer (score 0):

This is quite an ambitious project for someone who is completely new to DSP, but you can start by reading about the [overlap-add](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Overlap%E2%80%93add_method) method, which is essentially the method you need for your FFT-filter-IFFT approach to cleaning up this data. You should also check out the DSP StackExchange site [dsp.stackexchange.com](http://dsp.stackexchange.com), where the theoretical background and application of frequency domain filtering is covered in several similar questions/answers.

Comment: Thank's again Paul, I know it's ambitious but as someone famous once said "We choose to go...not because it is easy, but because it is hard". I will look into KissFFT but FFTW look very efficient and processing this "signal" must be the same thing as processing an audio signal (much larger sampling rate though). There are a lot of questions here regarding audio processing and often your answers seem to do the job for the lost ones...
Can I use an audio thread to dive into this problem with FFTW ?

Comment: KissFFT is also quite efficient - for seismic data with its low sample rate you probably don't need to worry too much about efficiency either, so just getting something working is probably more of a priority. You might even consider prototyping this first in MATLAB (or its free equivalent Octave), since this will be very quick to implement and you will learn a lot in the process and gain confidence, before moving on to an implementation in C/C++ with your FFT library of choice.

Comment: Yeah, I was looking into kissFFT and it seems to be a simpler way to go. I will do that, you're the skilled one and I should listen to you.

Comment: Good choice - KissFFT also has no potentially tricky licensing issues, unlike FFTW. And you can always change FFT library later if you decide that you made the wrong choice - it's only really a "black box" as far as your implementation is concerned. Also note that the KissFFT author participates on StackOverflow.

Comment: One last question (for today ;-) ), must I look into "windowing" concepts to implement what is asked to me ?

Comment: There are two aspects to "windows" in this context - first is the choice of window *size*, which is the number of points which you will process for each successive block, e.g. 1024 or 2048 - the choice will depend on your required frequency resolution. Second is the application of a window *function* (e.g. Hamming), which is usually required when performing spectral analysis, but which is not required for your frequency filtering operation.

Comment: Thank's Paul, merry Christmas to you and your loved ones. Don't worry, I'll be back ! ;-)

Comment: Thanks, and good luck with your project - I'm going to be travelling until early Jan so I might not be around to answer questions for a week or so, but I'll try and catch up when I get back. In the mean time: Joyeux Noël et Bonne Année ! 

Comment: You need to find a balance between time resolution and frequency resolution. This is somewhat related to Heisenberg uncertainty. You need a long window to be certain of a frequency event, but a short window to keep certainty on the location of time events. -- For that reason, the Gabor transform and later wavelet transforms were invented. Using a sliding window with a continuous window function is similar to the idea of the Gabor transform. -- You need to imagine that in the FFT, the end of the window is wrapped around to the start, if a jump results, the FFT will contain artificial defects.

Comment: Thank's LutzL for your answer. The function I am coding is not a real-time one for the moment. The end user will set a range of data he wants the "FFT filtering" to be applied on. We do not want FFT real time processing on our servers for now (maybe later when I will be more familiar with all this DSP). So, after reading a lot on the overlap-add method (as suggested by Paul R) I'm still wondering if it's the right way to go for me but I must admit that it is very interesting and gives me a more global understanding of all the field I'm dealing with.

Comment: The average number of points I will process is 1024 which corresponds to 1.42 hours of data. I was thinking about starting with a 1024 sized window. I also heard of wavelets transform and have found many libraries available on the Internet but I'm not sure if it's really needed here.KissFFT is up and running, but, as PAUL R said, it's just a black box, and the real work is before AND after FFT/IFFT.  Off course, I'm still struggling with all these concepts but day after day, post after post, I'm getting more confident and more familiar.

Comment: I just need a little help for the start and I hope to be able to pull this out on my own for the rest. Happy new year everyone, may the force be with us for 2014.